Detect if a Django related object has been prefetched via select_related
Let's say I have the following models:
class Product:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ProductVersion:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


For a given ProductVersion object, is there anyway to detect if the Product object was prefetched via select_related? For example:
# Yes, "product" was prefetched
ProductVersion.objects.select_related("product").first()

# No, "product" was NOT prefetched
ProductVersion.objects.first()

Looks like there's a way to do this was prefetch_related (see here) but I need it for selected_related.

Do you just want to check if the object is already loaded or do you specifically want to check whether it was loaded due to a selected_related?

Check if the object is loaded. Doesn't matter whether it was due to select_related or something else.

You can do that using check of JOIN word in query
queryset = ProductVersion.objects.select_related("product")
sql_query = str(queryset.query) # convert ORM query to SQL query
if 'JOIN' in sql_query:
    print("Product object was prefetched via select_related")
else:
    print("Product object was NOT prefetched via select_related")


There isn't a specific way to check if a field was populated due to a select_related, if your purpose though is to check whether accessing the field would result in a database query, you can check whether the field is cached or not by using the is_cached method on its descriptor:
cached_obj = ProductVersion.objects.select_related("product").first()
noncached_obj = ProductVersion.objects.first()


print(ProductVersion.product.is_cached(cached_obj)) # True
# OR in case you don't want to use the model class directly
print(cached_obj._meta.model.product.is_cached(cached_obj)) # True

print(ProductVersion.product.is_cached(noncached_obj)) # False
# OR in case you don't want to use the model class directly
print(noncached_obj._meta.model.product.is_cached(noncached_obj)) # False

